# sql - select column but remove non alphanumeric in result

Tags: mysql, regex

I have a table full of text stuff like usernames.
but in that table, there are nonalphanumeric values like @ and `

I want to get the results without any special characters, only all alphanumeric in the result,

I have the table like :

```
**user_names**
---------   
hitlerX`x`
---------
google_e
---------
@apples
---------
b-e-a-n-s
---------
@mango@
---------
_-amen_-
---------
```

I want the result like

```
**user_names** 
---------
hitlerXx    
---------    
googlee   
---------   
apples   
---------    
beans   
---------   
mango
---------   
amen
```

so far I've tried :

```
 SELECT * FROM table WHERE column REGEXP '^[A-Za-z0-9]+$'
```

Comment: MySQL does not have any built in regex _replace_ functionality.  `REGEXP`, which you are attempting to use, only supports matching, but not replacement.  You might have to handle this outside MySQL, or build your own UDF.

Comment: Do you know how many non alpha characters could be present?  Or is that not known?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen , i don't know, maybe there is query for it

Comment: Not the best way, but if nothing works, you can try something like this.



select
 replace( 
  replace( 
   replace( 
    replace( 
      some_column
    , '`','')
   , '_','')
  , '-', '')
 , '@', '') as user_names
from
some_table;

Comment: MariaDB has `REGEXP_REPLACE`.  Otherwise GIGO -- Garbage In Garbage Out.